# Flash CS3 movie fails in browser

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, cs3

My AS3-heavy project tests fine in the IDE, but some parts don't work in the browser when published. Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

It might help if you provide some more specific information on what's not working.  Can you post a link?  Furthermore, are any parts of your project referencing any remote objects?  If so, you might want to make sure your remote objects are located where your app expects them to be.  You may also need to add a crossdomain.xml to your server root if you're doing any cross site scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Cross domain issues?

Case sensitivity on a non-windows server?

You can always initiate a remote debug with the flash debugger to establish the cause. The docs explain how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

shot in the dark - are you running the correct version of the flash player in the browser? keep in mind that the browser installed player and the IDE player are not necessarilly in sync.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions. I'm very new to this and I think I might have found the solution: my .swf contains sounds and graphics and, until now, had no preloader. With a proper preloader (courtesy of Lee Brimelow's tutorial at Gotoandlearn.com) it seems to work OK. Thanks again.